# Непонятная проблема с указателями

Tags: c++, указатели

Пытаюсь я инициализировать данные для bitmap-изображения (заголовок `info` и пиксели `bits`) через такую функцию:

```
VOID MakeBitmap (BITMAPINFO* info, BYTE *bits, int w, int h)
{
    info = (BITMAPINFO*)new BYTE[w * h * 3 + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];
    ZeroMemory(info, w * h * 3 + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* ph = &info->bmiHeader;
    ph->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    ph->biWidth = w;
    ph->biHeight = h;
    ph->biPlanes = 1;
    ph->biBitCount = 24;
    ph->biSizeImage = w * h * 3;
    bits = (BYTE*)info + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
}
```

Инициализируется всё нормально. Но как только я пробую получить доступ к элементу массива `bits[i]`, программа вылетает, как будто там ничего нет. Также это не работает, если выделять для `bits` отдельный блок памяти.

В чём тут проблема?

Comment: В каком месте программа вылетает? Я бы ставил на то, что Вы меняете локальную копию `bits`, а то что передается в ф-цию не меняется - проверьте это сами с помощью отладчика или отладочного вывода содержимого переменных. Делов-то на 5 минут. С `info` тоже самое. Решений два. Оба ведут к изменению прототипа ф-ции:

`VOID MakeBitmap (BITMAPINFO** info, BYTE** bits, int w, int h)`
или
`VOID MakeBitmap (BITMAPINFO*& info, BYTE*& bits, int w, int h)`

И уточните что есть in-параметры, а что out.

Comment: с info нет проблем. Передается указатель, и по нему создается массив данных. Это правильное использование указателя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таком описании

```
VOID MakeBitmap (BITMAPINFO* info, BYTE *bits, int w, int h)
```

bits - это указатель на область памяти, через него вы можете менять эту область, но вы не можете менять сам указатель. Когда вы выйдите из функции переданный bits (его значение) останется без изменения, хотя в функции вы его меняли. 
Если я правильно понял вашу идею, вам надо сделать

```
VOID MakeBitmap (BITMAPINFO* info, BYTE **bits, int w, int h)
...
*bits=(BYTE*)info+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
```

Так по выходу из функции вы будите иметь новый указатель на созданную память.
Вызов:

```
BYTE * my_bits;
...
MakeBitmap(... &my_bits ...);
```

но сдается мне что архитектурно это лучше решать классом с полем битов внутри, и нормальными полями - заголовком